# VS code - xxd: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, xxd

I would like to use the xxd tool in my VS code terminal in my Ubuntu 22.0403 LTS machine but I get a  `bash: xxd: command not found` in the terminal.  In the standard ubuntu terminal I can use the xxd tool and it works.  I use the `whereis` command and find that it is in usr/bin  and can see it when I navigate to the directory.

[image]

[image]

When I do this in VS Code nothing comes up when I use the `whereis` command and I can’t find it in the directory.  So I believe this is obviously missing for some strange reason.
[image]

[image]

I have tried reinstalling xxd with no results.  Not sure why this would be.  In my `.bashrc` I have `export PATH=”$PATH:/usr/bin/”` thinking that perhaps my path was not setup correctly but that didn’t work either.
Here is my output when I `echo $PATH`  `root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.ghcup/bin:/root/.cabal/bin`

Also here is my About section of VS Code
[image]

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: 1) please post the output of `echo $PATH` in your VS Code terminal. 2) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: Woah, why is Bash running as root in VSC? (The `#` prompt means root, `$` means normal user.) Even if that's not related to the problem, that seems unwise.

Comment: Is VSCode connected to another machine? There are other differences between the file listings beyond just `xxd`.

Comment: it is running in a docker container

Comment: @mrsargent Yup, there's your problem.

Comment: I appologize for my ignorance as I am a .net transplant trying to write my wrongs with Linux. Is this something I can change in the settings to point to my user as opposed to the root?

Comment: @mrsargent No need to apologize :) I'm not actually sure how to fix it since I've never used Docker with VSC myself and I don't know how that'd be configured.